# Why is the array's length not being updated, causing an index out of bounds error?

Tags: java, arrays, encryption

It appears that the size of my 2D array, `EncryptedArr`, is not getting updated within the `encryptData` method.

This method is meant to encrypt a string (given within the main method) into an integer array. In order to see if the loops are actually placing data into the array correctly, I need the size of the array to match the data going into it.

```java
static void encryptData(String toEncrypt)
{
   stringLength = toEncrypt.length()
   encryptedArr = new int[stringLength][stringLength]
   for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex <= stringLength; rowIndex++)
   {
      for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < encryptedArr[rowIndex].length; 
                                                          columnIndex++)
      {
         while (indexOfString <= stringLength)
         {
            charToEncrypt = toEncrypt.charAt(indexOfString)
            charValue = charToEncrypt;
            encryptedArr[rowIndex][columnIndex] += charValue;
            indexOfString++;
         }
      }
   }
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   String thing = "1";
   encryptData(thing);
   System.out.println("Here is the array: "+ encryptedArr);
}
```

`charAt` is causing a "String Index Out Of Bounds" error that I believe is due to the size of the array not getting updated to match the size of the String being encrypted. The main method is supposed to print the array in its entirety. Both `EncryptData` and Main methods are above. Why is the code updating the array size not working, and what can be done to fix it?

Comment: For a start the code that you post is not valid. Second you call `encryptedArr = new int[stringLength][stringLength]` once, and `stringlength` is your example is `1` and furthermore `rowIndex <= stringLength` will cause the stated problem

Comment: Arrays are not resizable. Which part of the code did you think would do that?

Comment: My mistake. Its been a couple months since i last wrote code for arrays, so I'm a bit rusty and seem to be only making simple errors. I guess I should have been more patient and went over my code a few more times before posting. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex <= stringLength; rowIndex++){ //here
    for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < encryptedArr[rowIndex].length;columnIndex++){
         while (indexOfString <= stringLength){
          charToEncrypt = toEncrypt.charAt(indexOfString)
          charValue = charToEncrypt;
          encryptedArr[rowIndex][columnIndex] += charValue;
          indexOfString++;
     }
  }
```

}

In your first for loop you have set repetition condition to less than or equal to stringlength so when the rowIndex becomes equal to stringlength the call to the encryptedArr will give you an error because the highest index of array is always 1 less than size of array.